# Stylelint error in PhpStorm IDE : no configuration provided

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm, stylelint

I cannot make stylelint to work in PhpStorm

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "K:/dev/npm packages/node_modules/stylelint/bin/stylelint.js" -f json --stdin-filename ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\:/dev/D8/themes/amu_www/css/style.css
K:\:\dev\D8\themes\amu_www\css\style.css
Error: No configuration provided for K:\:\dev\D8\themes\amu_www\css\style.css
    at module.exports (K:\dev\npm packages\node_modules\stylelint\lib\utils\configurationError.js:8:28)
    at stylelint._fullExplorer.load.then.then.config (K:\dev\npm packages\node_modules\stylelint\lib\getConfigForFile.js:47:15)

Process finished with exit code 78
```

I have placed a `stylelintrc.json` config file about everywhere I could think of but I don't know in which folder it is supposed to be put.

Answer (score 3):

it was a .stylintrc.json and placing it just above the app working directory makes it foundable

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that my Webstorm IDE is always looking for the configuration file in the project root directory, while my `stylelint.config.js` was located in `configs/stylelint.config.js`.

I've solved by moving it to the root.

Comment: Where do you guys get these config files from? I don't find a stylelint.config.js or package.json anywhere.